# run id from az ml cli

Tags: azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

How to pass run id of experiment as tag information of model ?

I want to run experiment and register model with tag information with run id of experiment in az ml cli in Azure DevOps Build pipeline.

- run experiment
  az ml run submit-script  -e test -d myenv.yml train.py
- model register
  az ml model register -n mymodel -p sklearn_regression_model.pkl --tag "run id"= ????

I can't figure out how to get run id from experiment run from az ml cli and pass it to --tag argument. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you all. 
My requirements have changed and was able to code in Azure DevOps Pipeline.

With option -t run.json, experiment run informationn is stored in run.json

```
az ml run submit-script  -e $(experiment)  -d myenv.yml  -t run.json train-titanic.py
```

I want to register model outside the experiment run using run.json.

```
az ml model register --name mlops-model --experiment-name $(experiment) -f run.json -t ../release-pipeline/model.json --asset-path outputs/decision_tree.pkl
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2BRg.png)

Answer (score 0):

The run ID information is passed along automatically if you register a model from a run. You do not need to manually tag it.

Answer (score 0):

```
az ml run list --experiment-name experiment
```

This command returns a list of details about runs for this experiment , the run id should also be included.

To add or update a tag, use the following command:

```
az ml run update -r runid --add-tag quality='fantastic run'
```

For details ,please refer to this [docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/service/how-to-manage-runs.md#using-the-cli-1).